# .display() error on Pandas DataFrame in PySpark (Databricks)

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I keep getting the following error when running `df.display()` in the Databricks environment (using PySpark), however this is a `pandas` DataFrame, so I don't understand where this error comes from.

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:437: UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  Expected bytes, got a 'int' object
Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' is set to true.
  warn(msg)
TypeError: field Registratie: Can not merge type  and
```

I do not get this error on other DataFrames in the same notebook, so it is not just a notebook setting. This dataset also does not have weird data types or duplicate columns:

```
Out[25]: Registratie            object
Vluchtnr.              object
Positie                object
Melder                 object
Reden                  object
Extra                  object
datetime       datetime64[ns]
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: are any of your `object` columns mixed data types? if any or all of your `object` columns can be converted to a string or an int data type, you could try doing that first